# Save user preferences in a JSP

Tags: jquery, jsp

I am developing a page wherein i need to save some of the user's preferences and when he visits the page next time, he should see the same look as before. 
 Each user has the choice of keeping or deleting a menu item in the page. If he wants to add the deleted menu item later on, he should be able to do so. 
I want to design this using JSP  technologies. I really don't want to use cookies because if it is turned off, its of no use. Can anyone please let me know how to store the user preferences and retrieve whenever he wants.

Comment: "I really don't want to use cookies because if it is turned off, its of no use" — So what? Very few people disable cookies. People who do expect to have things like preferences fail to save… that's part of the point of turning them off.

Comment: Save in database then.however cookies is better option

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you have 3 option.

1. Use cookies (but as you said this is not acceptable)
2. Use session control (this has the limitation that if the session expires then the server will not be able to identify the user)
3. Using a database to store user information (and upon login the user should see the appropriate UI)

That's all your options pretty much. You see, the problem is how the server should identify a user...

Comment: Most session systems depend on cookies, so that probably won't work. Most login systems depend on sessions, so that probably won't work.

Comment: You implied that options 2 and 3 were different from "using a cookie"

Comment: actually option 3 is not the same a using a cookie, isnt it?

Comment: How is the server going to track the logged in state without using a cookie?

Comment: You expect the user to type in their username and password every time they load a new page from the server?

Comment: Could you give any examples for   Use cookies (but as you said this is not acceptable)
Use session control (this has the limitation that if the session expires then the server will not be able to identify the user)

Comment: Am expect to load every time user prefered  sortable pie charts , whence user click the save button next time user goes that page directly displays on before his click/save pie charts , am using jsp, jquery